# How to compile curl 7.35 and use it in project?

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I built libcurl and added it to project (specified include directory, library directory and library to use: libcurl.lib/libcurl_imp.lib - I both tried to compile and link static and dynamic library). In both cases (static/dynamic) I faced following:

```
1>tmp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _curl_easy_cleanup referenced in function "void __cdecl perform(char *)" (?perform@@YAXPAD@Z)
1>tmp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _curl_easy_perform referenced in function "void __cdecl perform(char *)" (?perform@@YAXPAD@Z)
1>tmp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _curl_easy_setopt referenced in function "void __cdecl perform(char *)" (?perform@@YAXPAD@Z)
1>tmp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _curl_easy_init referenced in function "void __cdecl perform(char *)" (?perform@@YAXPAD@Z)
1>C:\Users\Public\Documents\Project\curl-7.35.0\Debug\tmp.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
```

All solutions I found was different variations of "add libcurl.lib".

Now just to clarify my configuration:

dynamic: include directory specified, library directory specified, libcurl_imp.lib specified as additional dependency, libcurl.dll copied to the directory where executable files should be generated.

static: include directory specified, library directory specified, libcurl.lib specified as additional dependency.

using vs2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's silly but I was trying to use x64 library in x32 project.